# Error picking up the user's avatar (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

> Code

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) =>{

// at the top of your file
const discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require("../config");

// inside a command, event listener, etc.
const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setTitle('Créditos do Os Profissionais')
    .setURL('https://discord.gg/')
    .setAuthor('Effy', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png', 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/15303029/meredithgrey')
    .setDescription('Criador do grupo e desenvolvedor do BOT')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/1oHJJZQ.png')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Créditos de equipe', value: 'Equipe gestora' },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: 'Snoot', value: 'Owner', inline: true },
        { name: 'Texugo', value: 'Owner', inline: true },
    )
    .addField('Leo', 'Owner', true)
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/1oHJJZQ.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter(message.author.username, message.author.avatar);

    message.channel.send(embed);
}
module.exports.config = {
    name: "credits",
    aliases: ["creditos"]
}
```

> Error:

```
(node:5676) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.footer.icon_url: Scheme "fbea7946b1cf05e3bfbff344733ba775" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https').
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\RemakeTO\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\RemakeTO\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:5676) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5676) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**Since when I started using discord.js V12 i walk with many doubts and one of them is, how to catch the avatar of a user? Can someone help me? I know it's a stupid doubt but I really don't know**

Comment: If you don't already know about the discord.js docs. Try looking there, https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message.author.avatar` is not a method. You need `message.author.avatarURL`

```js
//author's avatar:
.setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL);
```

As mentioned above, try using the [docs](http://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// In discord.js v12
message.author.displayAvatarURL()
```

Answer (score -1):

I was having a similar issue. The problem was that Discord was being sent the embed before the promise of fetching the user and image was fulfilled. This is the code I used to get this functionality.

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
let thanos = client.users.fetch('IDHERE');
thanos.then(function(result1) {
    //put your code that uses the result1 (the user object) here
    //for example, you could put your entire embed in here and
    //in setFooter you could use result1.displayAvatarURL()
});
```